# Force single Linux application over VPN

Tags: ssh, vpn

I would like to force all connections that a specific application (transmission) uses over a OpenVPN connection.

So far, my VPN provider pushes a default route.

I know that transmission can set a "bind-address-ipv4" option.
I also know that iptables can match network connections to users and e.g. route all of the transmission-user's connections over the openvpn interface.

My problem is that I'm not exactly sure which one is a cleaner approach and how to exactly do that.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your layout. Do you want VPN clients to route application traffic through the VPN?

Comment: I have a homeserver with transmission and a few other applications on it and an openvpn account at a VPN provider.

I would like to have ONLY transmission be routed over the OpenVPN connection, all other software can use the regular internet connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the solution I went for:

- I used a regular SSH connection and created a socks proxy using "-D $PORT"
- I used [Proxychains](http://proxychains.sourceforge.net/) to force XBMC through the socks Proxy. That way I can use the [Hulu Plugin](http://code.google.com/p/bluecop-xbmc-repo/).
- I used [Deluge](http://deluge-torrent.org/) instead of Transmission because Deluge supports setting a proxy and doesn't even need proxy chains